# TSQL Cursor calls Stored Procedure 'View Nesting Level Exceeded'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Being a bit of a SQL Newb, I tried to create a SQL script to execute a stored procedure on a number of rows using a cursor. I found the code to create the cursor and the stored procedure works as expected.

However, sometimes during execution I get the error

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Here is the SQL script in question. Any ideas why I get this error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_MigrateRenewalOptions
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @OrderId VARCHAR(255) = NULL
    DECLARE @RenewalId INT = 0

    DECLARE @DiscountCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL
    DECLARE @UpgradeCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL
    DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(255) = NULL

    DECLARE rCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT RenewalId FROM t_Renewals WHERE DiscountCode IS NOT NULL AND UpgradeCode IS NOT NULL

    OPEN rCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM rCursor INTO @RenewalId   

    -- Iterate over t_Renewals with DiscountCode, UpgradeCode
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

      SELECT @OrderId = OrderId from t_Renewals where RenewalId = @RenewalId
      SELECT @DiscountCode = DiscountCode from t_Renewals where RenewalId = @RenewalId
      SELECT @UpgradeCode = UpgradeCode from t_Renewals where RenewalId = @RenewalId
      SELECT @ProductCode = ProductCode from t_Order Where OrderId = @OrderId

      -- Create renewal options for the t_Renewal entry 
      EXEC p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions @OrderId

      -- Migrate the DiscountCode, UpgradeCode from the renewal record 
      UPDATE t_Renewal_Option 
      SET CouponCode = @DiscountCode
      WHERE RenewalId = @RenewalId AND OptionType = 0 AND CouponCode IS NULL

      UPDATE t_Renewal_Option 
      SET CouponCode = @UpgradeCode
      WHERE RenewalId = @RenewalId AND OptionType = 1 AND CouponCode IS NULL

      -- NULL the Renewal record DiscountCode, UpgradeCode 
      UPDATE t_Renewals 
      SET DiscountCode = NULL, UpgradeCode = NULL 
      WHERE RenewalId = @RenewalId

      FETCH NEXT FROM rCursor INTO @RenewalId   
    END

    CLOSE rCursor   
    DEALLOCATE rCursor
END
GO
```

One thing I noted, that the statement

```
-- Create renewal options for the t_Renewal entry 
EXEC p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions @OrderId
```

returns a set, e.g. if you run this code outside of a stored procedure, inside SQL Server Management Studio, you get several sets of results in the output window. Is this the cause? Is it possible to dump the data as I don't need the returned rows from `p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions`

**EDIT: As requested, here is the code for p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions
(   
    @OrderId VARCHAR(255) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(255);
    SELECT @ProductCode = ProductCode FROM t_Order WHERE OrderId = @OrderId;

    DECLARE @StaticOptionCount INT;
    SET @StaticOptionCount = dbo.f_QueryRenewalOptionCount(@ProductCode);

    DECLARE @OptionCount INT;
    SELECT @OptionCount = COUNT(*) FROM t_Renewal_Option ro INNER JOIN t_Renewals r ON r.RenewalId = ro.RenewalId WHERE r.OrderId = @OrderId
    IF (@OptionCount != @StaticOptionCount)
    BEGIN
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
        BEGIN TRANSACTION   
            SELECT @OptionCount = COUNT(*) FROM t_Renewal_Option ro INNER JOIN t_Renewals r ON r.RenewalId = ro.RenewalId WHERE r.OrderId = @OrderId
            IF (@OptionCount != @StaticOptionCount)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @RenewalId INT;
                SELECT @RenewalId = RenewalId FROM t_Renewals r WHERE r.OrderId = @OrderId;

                DELETE FROM t_Renewal_Option WHERE RenewalId = @RenewalId;

                INSERT INTO t_Renewal_Option (RenewalId, OptionProductCode, OptionType, LastUpdated) 
                SELECT @RenewalId, sro.OptionProductCode, sro.OptionTypeId, GETDATE()
                FROM t_Static_Renewal_Option sro
                WHERE sro.ProductCode = @ProductCode

            END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END

    SELECT ro.* FROM t_Renewal_Option ro INNER JOIN t_Renewals r ON r.RenewalId = ro.RenewalId WHERE r.OrderId = @OrderId

END
GO
```

f_QueryRenewalOptionCount simply does a select:

```
 -- f_QueryRenewalOptionCount
 SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM t_Static_Renewal_Option o WHERE o.ProductCode = @ProductCode
```

Triggers wise, I don't think we have any triggers. There is a trigger on the t_Order table on INSERT but apart from that, nothing else.

**UPDATE 12-SEP-14:**

This 'works' but I don't understand the problem fully. I wrapped the EXEC call into a Begin/End Transaction

Note this script is called once to migrate some old part of the schema to a new part. Its not performance intensive and just has to 'work once'

Comment: What's the stored proc?  Why are you using a cursor in the first place? Likely this can be achieved without the cursor.

Comment: Heh, C# coders create such linear sql code.  There are a few clean up items you could do here, but unless speed is a worry, it's functional.  Have you tried without a cursor?  I think you will need to share the code behind p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions to get an answer here though.  You mention management studious, so I assume SQL server.  what version, 2008, 2012?

Comment: Because - as @Twelfth points out - I'm a c# coder :) Speed is not a worry. I just want to execute some logic for each row in t_Renewals. Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Without the code for `p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions`, we really can't help any further. No the result sets from this stored procedure will not be causing the issue - they are ignored.

Comment: I appreciate all your help, I've added the procedure to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a trigger on any of your tables? If an update trigger updates its own table, it will trigger itself again, which will update the table again, etc.

Do you use view or function anywhere in your code? Views can call on other views or functions, which call other views / functions.

Comment: I've updated above. Only trigger is on the t_Order table on insert. The procedure calls a function which only does a select

Answer (score 1):

The cursor here, while makes my skin crawl, is likely not the cause of the error your seeing. Without being able to see what the nested stored procedure is doing, this is just an educated guess, but that's probably where the issue lies.

The error you're seeing happens whenever a recursive SQL operation basically gets stuck in an infinite loop. The two ways I have had it happen is with a poorly written recursive CTE (basically a table which infinitely unions to itself) or when, as is more likely in this case, a store procedure calls a stored procedure which calls a stored procedure... and so on down the line. For instance (and I haven't tested this) if p_selectOrCreateRenewalOptions called p_MigrateRenewalOptions, you'd probably see a similar error.

Comment: No it doesn't call anything else. What about wrapping the EXEC p_SelectOrCreateRenewalOptions inside a Begin/End? It does update the t_Renewal_Option table but nothing else

Comment: Does the fact that I'm effectively calling a stored procedure in a loop not lead to infinite recursion?